# How to get all solutions which causes to optimal result in Gurobi

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gurobi

I have an implementation in Gurobi in python. My problem has different choices of selecting parameters to reach the optimal result. Now I need all solutions which reach the optimal value of result. How can I get them ? I know the blow code which just returns one solution.

```
if m.status == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL:
        for v in m.getVars():
              print (v.varname, v.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the [SolutionPool](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/solution_pool.html#sec:SolutionPool). You can specify how many solutions you want Gurobi to return.